# Program running even after Force shutdown and unplugging

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze, gaming

I was playing a game which hung so I had to force shutdown my laptop.

When I forced shutdown the laptop, it took about 5 secs for keyboard backlights to go off after screen went off (usually both go off at same time)....
When laptop was fully off, I unplugged the AC power (note no battery is connected).

After a while I plugged in AC and turned on the laptop. While booting up I could hear the game running in background. And when I logged in, the game was still running. I managed to restart my laptop and then the game went off.

Any ideas to what might have caused this? I usually have a problem of disk usage at 100% even when not running anything, not sure if linked but the only problem with laptop I have noticed recently.

Answer (score 0):

The laptop was most likely not shut down, but was put in hibernation mode. (Contents of memory saved on disk, and restored at next start).

You can change what to do when power button is pressed / lid is closed in `Power Options` --> `Choose what the power buttons do` in the control panel.

I never use hibernation, since it has has a history of not working properly. (And besides, if I press the power button, then i really want to shut down the computer)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Laptop probably didnt register the holding down of the power button as it was lagging, instead acted as if the key was only pressed once leading to hibernation.

Comment: However what concerns me is that I unplugged my laptop from wall. Since the internal battery had been previously removed, removing AC should have shut down my laptop.

Comment: Or is it possible for a laptop to hibernate even without any battery? (No battery or AC was plugged in.. so basically there was no charge present in laptop.. whatever charge in it was also drained by holding down the power button to remove the static.)

Comment: Yes, in hibernation the power is completely off, since the contents of the RAM is stored on disk.